# How to play a recorded audio file?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I'm using MediaRecorder class to record an audio file and I used

```
final String MEDIA_OUTPUT_FILE = "MyOutPutFile";
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(MEDIA_OUTPUT_FILE);'
```

to give a name to my output file.

I also know how to Play an Audio File from Resources:

```
MediaPlayer mpRes = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.audiofile);
mpRes.start();'
```

My Question Is, Now, how to play the recorded file while I dont know where my MEDIA_OUTPUT_FILE is saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using constant as argument for `mediaRecorder.setOutputFile()` use a variable like below.

```
private String filePath;
filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
filePath += "/myrecording.mpeg";
```

Then pass the filePath variable as the argument as follow;

```
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(filePath);
```

Then you can play the recorded file as follows;

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

That's it.